# How to declare array of pointer to char * array

Tags: c

The issue is accessing each address of the array of pointer is merging my data to the subsequent ones

[image: Code in the image is merging my data]

Comment: Please post the code as text.

Comment: Strings in C are NULL-terminated. Add '\0' to the end of each.

Comment: (Your char arrays are not C strings, because they are not terminated by null.)

Comment: Please edit your post and show the actual content as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. See here for details https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* String are NULL terminated, you might have read comments in question */
unsigned char mydata1[] = {0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x00};
unsigned char mydata2[] = {0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x00};
unsigned char mydata3[] = {0x47, 0x48, 0x49, 0x4A, 0x00};

/* Here I have used a NULL terminated array so that we can traverse 
 * even if we do not know the length of array 
 */
unsigned char *charPtr[] = 
{
        mydata1,
        mydata2,
        mydata3,
        NULL
};

int main()
{
        int i;

        for (i = 0; charPtr[i] != NULL; i++) {
                printf("%s\n", charPtr[i]);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in remark your arrays are not terminated by a null character, this is why *printf* continues after them.

You get that result because your arrays are placed in memory one after one by the compiler, and finally there is a null character for an other reason

So the minimal changes are

```
unsigned char mydata1[] = {0x41,0x42,0x43, 0};
unsigned char mydata2[] = {0x44,0x45,0x46, 0};
unsigned char mydata3[] = {0x47,0x48,0x49,0x4A, 0}
```

but that way to do supposes your compiler uses ASCII code and this is not readable, better to do

```
unsigned char mydata1[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 0};
unsigned char mydata2[] = {'D', 'E', 'F', 0};
unsigned char mydata3[] = {'G','H','I','J', 0};
```

or more simple :

```
unsigned char mydata1[] = "ABC";
unsigned char mydata2[] = "DEF";
unsigned char mydata3[] = "GHIJ";
```

---

Out of that

- doing `for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)` is *dangerous* because if you modify the number of elements into *charPtr* you need to also modify the *for*, one way is to add a NULL pointer to mark the end of the pointer list and to iterate up to a NULL pointer, an other is to iterate while `i < (sizeof(charPtr)/sizeof(charPtr[0]))`.
- it is better to not use *int* to type *i* but `size_t` because this is the natural type for an index